# Are both generic type and argument necessary in this TypeScript code?

Tags: typescript, generics, enums, runtime

This is hard to explain without source code, so take a look at this snippet:

```js
type Type1 = { num1: number; str1: string };
type Type2 = { num2: number; str2: string };
type Type3 = { num3: number; str3: string };
type Type4 = { num4: number; str4: string };

enum MyEnum {
  ONE,
  TWO,
  THREE,
  FOUR,
}

type MyTypes<T> = T extends MyEnum.ONE
  ? Type1
  : T extends MyEnum.TWO
  ? Type2
  : T extends MyEnum.THREE
  ? Type3
  : T extends MyEnum.FOUR
  ? Type4
  : never;

const urls = {
  [MyEnum.ONE]: 'http://one.com',
  [MyEnum.TWO]: 'http://two.com',
  [MyEnum.THREE]: 'http://three.com',
  [MyEnum.FOUR]: 'http://four.com',
};

const fetchData = (_url: string): unknown => ({
  // ...
});

export const myFun = <T extends MyEnum>(type: T) => {
  const data = fetchData(urls[type]);
  return { data: data as MyTypes<T> };
};

const one = myFun<MyEnum.ONE>(MyEnum.ONE);
const two = myFun<MyEnum.TWO>(MyEnum.TWO);
const three = myFun<MyEnum.THREE>(MyEnum.THREE);
const four = myFun<MyEnum.FOUR>(MyEnum.FOUR);
```

`myFun()` here receives the same twice:

- As generic type, used statically to type the `data` returned.
- As an argument, to be used in runtime to choose the right `url`

Note this works like a charm. Even writing something like `myFun<MyEnum.ONE>(MyEnum.TWO)` is not allowed as I don't allow passing a different types for generic and argument. Returned type is correctly typed and `myFun()` works as I need.

[image]

What is the problem? I find it ugly and I would like to use `myFun()` passing the type only once, in one of the following ways:

```js
const a = myFun<MyEnum.ONE>();  // Option 1
const b = myFun(MyEnum.ONE);    // Option 2
```

Is it possible?

I tried:

- Option 1 (using a generic only), but in runtime it is not available to select the proper `url`.
- Option 2 (using only the argument) as `const myFun = (type: MyEnum) => {...}`, but then I cannot assign the proper type to returned `data`.

**Note**: Any other suggestion to simplify things here is welcome. For instance, `MyTypes<T>` definition looks ugly for me but I don't know any other way to do it.

Comment: Use option 2 but dont remove the generic type from the function? And call it like `myFun(MyEnum.ONE)` ?

Comment: Is it possible I'm so stupid not to try it? Absolutely yes! Oh my god I think this is exaclty what I need! Thank you very much, @TobiasS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Tobias S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8613630/tobias-s) I've discovered that TypeScript does not need the generic to be provided when the function is called, as it infers it from the argument. So it is ok to define `myFun()` as follows:

```js
export const myFun = <T extends MyEnum>(type: T) => {
  const data = // ...
  return { data: data as MyTypes<T> };
};
```

But you can use it as

```js
const { data } = myFun(MyEnum.ONE);
```

And TypeScript will infer `data` type from the generic, infered from the value received as argument (as it is the same provided by the generic). It rocks!

```
 argument ------> generic --------> data
(provided)       (inferred)      (inferred)
```